# Decrypt hashed value

Tags: encryption

I was looking at a video game's xml prefrences document and it had this as one of its nodes

< shop_vehicle >
KEYxLjAKUydtZWRpdW1UYW5rJwpwMApTJ2luSGFuZ2FyJwpwMQp0cDIKLg==
< /shop_vehicle >

I am assuming that is some sort of hashed value, but I was curious if the "KEY" at the beginning or the == at the end ment anything, seeing as there are other nodes that start with the same value. If it does have some meaning would there be a way to decrypt this value?

here is another value

< inventory_shell > KEY0LjAKUydBUk1PUl9QSUVSQ0lORycKcDAKUydBUk1PUl9QSUVSQ0lOR19DUicKcDEKUydIT0xMT1dfQ0hBUkdFJwpwMgpTJ0hJR0hfRVhQTE9TSVZFJwpwMwpTJ215VmVoaWNsZUd1bicKcDQKUyIobHAwXG5jZ3VpLlNjYWxlZm9ybS51dGlscy5ndWlfaXRlbXNcbkludmVudG9yeVZlaGljbGVcbnAxXG5hKFMnIVxceDAyXFx4MDNcXHgwMFxceDA0XFx4MDBcXHhjOVxceDAwXFx4MDRcXHgwMFxceDA0XFx4MDBcXHgwNlxceDAwXFx4MDAnXG5wMlxuSTNcbihscDNcbkk2XG5hSTdcbmF0cDRcbmEuIgpwNQp0cDYKLg==
< /inventory_shell >

Answer (score 6):

You cannot "decrypt" hashes - the defining property of a hash is that the only way to find a content whose hash that matches the given hash value is to brute-force-test all possible contents.

Fortunately, this isn't a hash, it's merely [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (an *encoding*). In Python (or [online](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)):

```
>>> import base64
>>> s = b'KEYxLjAKUydtZWRpdW1UYW5rJwpwMApTJ2luSGFuZ2FyJwpwMQp0cDIKLg=='
>>> base64.b64decode(s)
"(F1.0\nS'mediumTank'\np0\nS'inHangar'\np1\ntp2\n."
```

On second thought, both values start with KEY, so it's likely the author of this format added some home-brewed encoding. Also, the content is not a plain string, but a binary data format.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a Base64 encoded string. Use a tool like this one to decode it: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/